# heroku application error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to access my ruby on rails app deployed through heroku, and all it's telling me is "application error, if you are the owner check your logs". I've looked through the logs and can't find anything of note, also I'm kind of new so I may have missed something. I've copied them below, if anyone could help me I'd really appreciate it!

```
    C:\Users\Nick\Projects\treebook>heroku logs
2014-01-15T08:20:18.102701+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/passwords/new.htm
l.erb within layouts/application (36.0ms)
2014-01-15T08:20:18.102646+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/
password/new host=ancient-coast-2223.herokuapp.com fwd="5.10.83.102" dyno=web.1
connect=10ms service=439ms status=200 bytes=1552
2014-01-15T09:25:51.904267+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-01-15T09:25:51.904941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-01-15T09:25:55.548293+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGT
ERM
2014-01-15T09:25:56.427897+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2014-01-15T09:25:56.427897+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-01-15T09:25:56.427897+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-01-15T09:25:56.427897+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
2014-01-15T09:25:56.427897+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
2014-01-15T09:25:56.427897+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-01-15 09:25:56] FATAL SignalE
xception: SIGTERM
2014-01-15T09:25:56.427897+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-01-15T09:25:56.427897+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-01-15T09:25:56.427897+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-15T09:25:56.427897+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2014-01-15T09:25:56.428173+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-15T09:25:56.428173+00:00 app[web.1]:    script/rails:6:in `require'
2014-01-15T09:25:56.428173+00:00 app[web.1]:    script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-01-15T09:25:56.428572+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-01-15 09:25:56] INFO  going t
o shutdown ...
2014-01-15T09:25:56.428792+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-01-15 09:25:56] INFO  WEBrick
::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-01-15T09:25:56.428946+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-01-15T09:25:58.317765+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-01-15T09:32:26.452396+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to start
ing
2014-01-15T09:32:26.452057+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2014-01-15T09:32:30.382574+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
undle exec rails server -p 8907`
2014-01-15T09:32:34.053928+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails
 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed
in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to
your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release
notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-h
as-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

2014-01-15T09:32:34.060479+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails
 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed
in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to
your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release
notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-h
as-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)

2014-01-15T09:32:34.659321+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-01-15T09:32:34.659321+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.6 application starting
 in production on http://0.0.0.0:8907
2014-01-15T09:32:34.659321+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2014-01-15T09:32:34.659321+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-01-15T09:32:34.659321+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by
 DATABASE_URL
2014-01-15T09:32:34.737822+00:00 app[web.1]:         SECURITY WARNING: No secret
 option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
2014-01-15T09:32:34.737822+00:00 app[web.1]:         This poses a security threa
t. It is strongly recommended that you
2014-01-15T09:32:34.737822+00:00 app[web.1]:         provide a secret to prevent
 exploits that may be possible from crafted
2014-01-15T09:32:34.737822+00:00 app[web.1]:         cookies. This will not be s
upported in future versions of Rack, and
2014-01-15T09:32:34.737822+00:00 app[web.1]:         future versions will even i
nvalidate your existing user cookies.
2014-01-15T09:32:34.737822+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-01-15T09:32:34.737822+00:00 app[web.1]:         Called from: /app/vendor/bu
ndle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abs
tract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
2014-01-15T09:32:35.643054+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-01-15 09:32:35] INFO  WEBrick
 1.3.1
2014-01-15T09:32:35.643054+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-01-15 09:32:35] INFO  ruby 2.
0.0 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-linux]
2014-01-15T09:32:35.643960+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-01-15 09:32:35] INFO  WEBrick
::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=8907
2014-01-15T09:32:36.101046+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to u
p
2014-01-15T09:32:36.557580+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/feed" for 5.10.83.23
at 2014-01-15 09:32:36 +0000
2014-01-15T09:32:36.557580+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-01-15T09:32:36.557580+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-01-15T09:32:36.733559+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StatusesController#in
dex as */*
2014-01-15T09:32:37.055549+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered statuses/index.html.erb
within layouts/application (5.2ms)
2014-01-15T09:32:37.073393+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 331ms (Views: 5
3.8ms | ActiveRecord: 146.1ms)
2014-01-15T09:32:37.070847+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/feed h
ost=ancient-coast-2223.herokuapp.com fwd="5.10.83.23" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms ser
vice=555ms status=200 bytes=1009
2014-01-15T10:39:20.861879+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-01-15T10:39:20.862709+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-01-15T10:39:26.152789+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGT
ERM
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349509+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349509+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-01-15 10:39:28] FATAL SignalE
xception: SIGTERM
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349509+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349509+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349736+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349509+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349736+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-01-15 10:39:28] INFO  WEBrick
::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349736+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349509+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349736+00:00 app[web.1]:    script/rails:6:in `require'
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349736+00:00 app[web.1]:    script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349736+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-01-15 10:39:28] INFO  going t
o shutdown ...
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349509+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349509+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349509+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/
2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-01-15T10:39:28.349509+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/ge
ms/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
2014-01-15T10:39:32.131310+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-01-15T17:28:52+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-01-15T17:29:41+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed
 to compile Ruby app
2014-01-15T17:34:16+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-01-15T17:34:57+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed
 to compile Ruby app
2014-01-15T17:36:21+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-01-15T17:53:09+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-01-15T17:53:50+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-01-15T17:53:51.149370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to start
ing
2014-01-15T17:53:50.636801+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy a01f9b0 by nico_dubus@hotma
il.com
2014-01-15T17:53:50.659462+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v14 created by nico_dubus@
hotmail.com
2014-01-15T17:53:55.447426+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
undle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 23616`
2014-01-15T17:53:57.870573+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: thin
2014-01-15T17:53:57.870573+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables wit
h `bundle install`
2014-01-15T17:53:59.771942+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-01-15T17:53:59.785195+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-01-15T17:53:59.785928+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2014-01-15T17:54:03.907763+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
undle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 57812`
2014-01-15T17:54:05.728365+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables wit
h `bundle install`
2014-01-15T17:54:05.728365+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: thin
2014-01-15T17:54:07.247758+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-01-15T17:54:07.266939+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-01-15T17:54:07.695808+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=ancient-coast-2223.herokuapp.com fwd="99.254.12.203
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T17:55:34.114731+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=ancient-coast-2223.herokuapp.com fwd="99.254.12.203
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T18:02:11.810789+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=ancient-coast-2223.herokuapp.com fwd="99.254.12.203
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T18:02:11.038318+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=ancient-coast-2223.herokuapp.com fwd="99.254.12.203
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T18:02:02.502227+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=ancient-coast-2223.herokuapp.com fwd="99.254.12.203
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T18:02:10.023155+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=ancient-coast-2223.herokuapp.com fwd="99.254.12.203
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T18:03:30.922365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=ancient-coast-2223.herokuapp.com fwd="99.254.12.203
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T18:03:33.847534+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=ancient-coast-2223.herokuapp.com fwd="99.254.12.203
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T18:03:32.869646+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=ancient-coast-2223.herokuapp.com fwd="99.254.12.203
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-01-15T18:05:34.688015+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path=/ host=ancient-coast-2223.herokuapp.com fwd="99.254.12.203
" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing thin

> 2014-01-15T17:53:55.447426+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p 23616`
>   2014-01-15T17:53:57.870573+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not
>   found: thin

In your Gemfile put

```
group :production do
  gem 'thin'  
end
```

Run bundle, commit & push to Heroku.  HTH?